# Значение слова "крутой"

Tags: жаргон, этимология

На современном сленге "крутой" - это целая совокупность понятий: сильный, смелый, умелый и т. д. Сейчас это слово уже, по-моему, практически вошло в язык уже не как сленговое. Но почему именно крутой? Крутым может быть обрыв, может быть вареное яйцо, но что-то ничего героического я в этом не вижу)))
При этом аналогичное значение в английском имеет слово "cool" - "прохладный".

Comment: Если Вы получили исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как правильный.

Answer (score 2):

Современное значение слова «крутой»  (обрывистый, резко меняющий направление)  непосредственно восходит к глаголу «крутить»  (приводить в круговое, вращательное движение), поэтому   «крутой» в исходном значении   - это кручёный:  таким образом мы получаем крутой овраг  с резко закрученным профилем.

Однако сам глагол «крутить»  является производным и имеет о.-с. основу  krot /kret, которая соотносится  со значениями «крепкий, сильный, грубый, яростный, энергично проявляющий себя», и кручение – это только один из способов такого проявления.
К примеру, Даль отмечает существование  диал. кретать/крятать/крянуть -  привести в движение (трогать, двигать, сдвигать, столкнуть с места, подать взад либо вперед): Кретать избу на пожаре. Река кренулась, лед тронулся. Тесто крянулось, стало бродить.

Поэтому у слова «крутой»  в словарях дополнительно отмечаются значения сильного проявления признака:  решительный, резкий,  очень сильный, чрезмерный.  Также: плотный, густой (о дыме, дожде),  густо замешанный, сваренный до густоты (тесто, яйцо).

Современный жаргонизм «крутой» как преуспевающий, удачливый, заслуживающий восхищения и уважения  в большей степени отражает именно эти качества.  Слово «крутой»  - это целый комплекс, описывающий деловые качества человека: решительность, энергичность, умение  настаивать на своем, проявлять свою волю, быстро реагировать  на ситуацию и принимать решения.

Comment: Вряд  ли  стоит  искать  причины  распространённости  этого  слова  в  этимологии.  Главное  знать,  что  оно  значит  сейчас.

Answer (score 1):

*Крутой* = *имеющий крутой нрав.* Так говаривали и в старину, ничего нового тут нет.

Comment: Правильно. Но  сейчас   значение  слова  шире.

Comment: Полагаю, слово "крутой" сначала стало обозначать примерно то же, что и слово "брутальный" в разговорной речи, то есть "выраженно мужественный", а затем превратилось в такую же "бессодержательную" оценку, как и слова "добрый" (изначально — "подходящий") и "хороший" (предположительно от того же корня, что и слова "храбрый, хоробрый").

Answer (score 1):

В английском языке помимо слова "cool", что больше означает "спокойный" и "уверенный", используется понятие "hard-boiled", что дословно значит "свареный вкрутую" и используется в значении, сходном со словом "крутой" в русском языке.

Некоторые источники называют популярный в штатах одноимённый китайский фильм 1992 года основой термина. http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=hard%20boiled

Не совсем ясно, мог ли термин попасть в китайский язык из русского и затем в английский или же наоборот.

Другие источники говорят, что термин впервые появился в детективной литературе жанра нуар. "Варёными вкрутую" называли детективов, не брезгающих применять насилие в ходе расследования. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardboiled

Comment: При чём тут "спокойный"? Не об этом значении речь. А "уверенный" вообще непонятно, откуда Вы взяли.

Answer (score 0):

В противоположность чему-то мягкому, жидкому, бесформенному...

Comment: Позволю себе напомнить старый анекдот. Приходит внучка к бабушке и спрашивает: - Вот, в книжке написано "крутой холм". Как это холм может быть крутой? Бывает - крутая тачка, крутой чувак, а холм?? Почесала бабушка репу, и отвечает: - Это очень просто, внученька! Холм крутой - значит на него хрен наедешь.

Answer (score 0):

Также: плотный, густой (о дыме, дожде), густо замешанный, сваренный до густоты (тесто, яйцо).

Ну как тут не вспомнить "круче нас могут быть только яйца"!

Answer (score -1):

Крутость: да, очень интересно!
Есть в латинском языке слово *crudus*, оттуда может, быть пришло это слово?!
Даже на немецком говорят *krude*, используют не только в значении варки яиц, но и в описании грубости, жестокости людей, в описании искусств, которые не точные и не изящные!
https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/krude